# can't insert a date in my tablle in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new in the SQL programming, I've created a table where I want to insert a a date  like

```
create table person (
   PANr integer not null,
   name Varchar(10),
   HNr integer not null,
   stuff_date date,
   constraint P_NR primary key (PANr)
);
```

insert into Personen values ('4711','Andreas''15','31.10.1958');

the creating of the table works but the insert command gives this error:

```
 SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
  01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

any Idea what's wrong here ?? 
thanks in advance

Comment: try insert a date as default DATE format "DD-MON-YY" format i.e (31-10-1958)

Comment: Don't use strings, use date literals: `date '1958-10-31'`.  http://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TO_DATE('31.10.1958', 'DD.MM.YYYY')`.

Comment: thanks for you answer but I think there a cmd that I can give at the beginning of my code so I don't have to use to_date every time I want to insert a date, any Idea how this could work ?

Answer (score 2):

You have another error.

```
insert into person
values
('4711','Andreas''15','31.10.1958');
```

First, you are quoting your integer values.  That may or may not cause a problem, but it's a bad idea.  Second, you need a comma between Andreas and 15.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `TO_DATE` function you can use the following:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd';
```

Now, your insert statement would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO PERSONEN VALUES('4711','Andreas','15','1958-10-31');
```

If you want to be more specific you can define the date format like this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
```

P.S. Please, pay attention on @Dan Bracuk answer.